# ELK : One or more required cgroup files or directories not found: /proc/self/cgroup

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I have configured the logstash configuration as below to read the logs generated by spring boot to push into elastic search, but index is not creating even though logstash started successfully,

Conf file:

```
input {
    file {
        path => "C:\workspace\app\logback\applogs.log"
        codec => "json"
        type => "logback"
    }
}
 
output {
    if [type]=="logback" {
         elasticsearch {
             hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
             index => "logback-test"
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Why in the world logstash logs this with `DEBUG` severity when it should be `ERROR`. I have the same problem, and it's not a slash vs backslash issue.

Answer (score 7):

You should change the character **from "\" to "/"** in path for **windows**, specially windows 10.
So, you can rewrite the path like the following:

```
 file {
        path => "C:/workspace/app/logback/applogs.log" // not like "C:\workspace\app\logback\applogs.log"
        codec => "json"
        type => "logback"
    }
```